# Property does not exist on type 'ReadOnly <{}>' after switching from `.js` to `.tsx` in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

After switching from JavaScript to TypeScript, I get the error:

> Property does not exist on type 'ReadOnly <{}>'

in this code:

`this.state.flashcards`

It seems that I need to define `flashcards` as a type, but when I change `flashcards: []` to `flashcards: any[]` it give me an error that any is being used as a value.

How can I get this could to compile in TypeScript as it does in JavaScript?

```
import React from 'react';
import Flashcard from './Flashcard';

const flashcards = require('../data/custom/itemType_flashcards.json');

class Main extends React.Component {
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            flashcards: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
            flashcards
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
                <div className="content">
                    {this.state.flashcards.map(flashcard => <Flashcard {...flashcard} key={flashcard.id} />)}
                </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Main;
```

Comment: Pretty sure not answer you are looking for but changing strict to false in tsconfig should make error go away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using typescript, `React.Component` is a generic which you can use to specify the types of your props and state. If you don't, the default is for props and state to be empty objects, which is then causing an error when you try to assign a state that isn't an empty object. So do something like the following:

```
interface MainState {
  flashcards: FlashcardProps[]; // You'll need to define the shape of FlashcardProps too
}

class Main extends React.Component<{}, MainState> {
  // The rest is unchanged
}
```